# Magento Cookies Changing Prevent Frontend Login

Tags: magento

When a customer tries to log in to the frontend of Magento they are redirected back to the login page without an error.  The problem appears to be that the new cookie is written, then immediately overwritten when logging in.  Here is a log of the Cookies set when logging in:

```
Cookie frontend added.  0o94icitv247nhh6l7op2csoe4  .domain.com 
Cookie frontend deleted.  0o94icitv247nhh6l7op2csoe4    .domain.com
Cookie frontend added.  no81giicmgscpkr14ho3m1rpv2  .domain.com
Cookie frontend changed.  0o94icitv247nhh6l7op2csoe4    .domain.com
Cookie frontend changed.  0o94icitv247nhh6l7op2csoe4    .domain.com
```

If I manually edit the frontend cookie to the value on the third line, then I am logged in.  Any idea on why it is being change (twice even) on lines 4 and 5?

I thought it might be an extension overwriting the `Mage_Core_Model_Session_Abstract_Varien` class, but a grep of the app/code directory doesn't show any classes extending that class.

-- UPDATE --

I'm still having this problem.  I've dug a little more (with XDEBUG/webgrind) and found that `Mage_Core_Model_Session_Abstract_Varien->start` is being called twice by:

```
Mage_Core_Model_Session_Abstract_Varien->init @ 162
Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->preDispatch @ 490
```

It looks like `preDispatch()` might be overwriting the session cookie.  Does this make sense?  I don't have much experience with Magento session handling, so I'm hoping somebody can help here.

Comment: I don't know if it will help your specific problem, but you should check why your grep is skipping code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Session/Abstract.php, or alternately why the class in that files doesn't extend Mage_Core_Model_Session_Abstract_Varien. (1.6.1, but probably applies to other versions)

Comment: Sorry, I guess I should have said there were no classes outside of the app/code/core that were extending that class.

Comment: Maybe you have session autostart enabled in you php.ini, virtual host settings, etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found the source of the double cookie.

TinyBrick Lightspeed Page Cache was adding a cookie at the sub-domain level that was confusing the cookie at the TLD:

```
        public static function buildCookie()
        {
                require_once 'app/Mage.php';
                $request = new Zend_Controller_Request_Http();
                session_set_cookie_params(
                         self::getCookieLifetime()
                        ,self::getDefaultCookiePath()
//                      ,$request->getHttpHost() // commented out to fix double cookie problem.
                        ,'.domain.com' // added to fix double cookie problem.
                        ,false
                        ,true
                );
                session_name('frontend');
                session_start();
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion there is an error in Magento core:

In Mage_Core_Model_Session_Abstract_Varien there is a code:

```
if (isset($cookieParams['domain'])) {
    $cookieParams['domain'] = $cookie->getDomain();
}
```

Which actually doesn't make sense. It should be:

```
if (!isset($cookieParams['domain'])) {
    $cookieParams['domain'] = $cookie->getDomain();
}
```

This avoid to have double "frontend" cookie.